How to fix Directus performance on AWS (CPU consumption)?
We have a Directus on AWS on t3.2xlarge instance (8 vCPUs/32GB RAM). The project is relatively small and doesn't really have any traffic. It uses Redis (AWS ElastiCache) and Postgress (AWS RDS).
It runs on Docker and I will attach a config.
The problem is that we have a lot of issue, when we start making even simple API calls to read from 1 collection without any queries, I see load on CPU in PM2 and then after some requests Directus freezes and starts return 502 error.
We tried to use different configurations, we use latest version but nothing helped. Does anyone have any ideas what can be the case?
We had different Directus instance in Docker (DB + Directus) and it worked well with old version (1 year ago or so).
  directus:
    restart: always
    image: directus/directus:11.0.2
    ports:
      - 80:80
    environment:
      CORS_ENABLED: 'true'
      PORT: '80'
      
      CORS_ORIGIN: 'true'
      CORS_METHODS: 'GET,POST,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS'
      KEY: '***'
      SECRET: '***'

      DB_CLIENT: 'pg'
      DB_HOST: '***.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com'
      DB_PORT: '5432'
      DB_DATABASE: 'postgres'
      DB_USER: '***'
      DB_PASSWORD: '***'

      STORAGE_LOCATIONS: 's3'
      STORAGE_S3_DRIVER: 's3'
      STORAGE_S3_KEY: '***'
      STORAGE_S3_SECRET: '***'
      STORAGE_S3_BUCKET: '***'
      STORAGE_S3_REGION: 'us-east-1'
      STORAGE_S3__ENDPOINT: 's3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'

      EMAIL_FROM: 'no-reply@***'
      EMAIL_TRANSPORT: 'mailgun'
      EMAIL_MAILGUN_API_KEY: '***'
      EMAIL_MAILGUN_DOMAIN: '***'

      CACHE_ENABLED: 'true'
      CACHE_STORE: 'redis'
      CACHE_AUTO_PURGE: 'true'
      REDIS: 'redis://***.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379'

      CONTENT_SECURITY_POLICY_DIRECTIVES__FRAME_SRC: "***"
      CONTENT_SECURITY_POLICY_DIRECTIVES__IMG_SRC: "array:'self',data:,https://*"

      PM2_INSTANCES: '8'
      PM2_AUTO_RESTART: 'true'
      
      PRESSURE_LIMITER_ENABLED: 'false'```

